# how to automatically share user content / entries from my web app to facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do apps like twitter and instagram accomplish this?

I've been searching for a while online, and have gone through the facebook api, but it seems an auth_token is needed for every post. It seems a login is required each time to obtain the auth_token.

I know there is also the option of using an inline share button: `<a href="https://facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.something.com" target="_blank"><img src="/images/fb_share.png" /></a>`

But again, the user would already have to be logged in.

Is there anyway to accomplish a feature where users select a preference in my app to automatically share their content / entries from my web app to their facebook?

what would the best workflow for this be?

Comment: You need to retrieve a long time token

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

Comment: @jonas w, Okay, so even in apps like twitter, the user would have to re-login / refresh the token after 60 days?

Comment: Well, twitter is a bit more important then you. However, what about asking the http://facebook.com/support/

Comment: I guess twitter is more important.. hurts my ego to admit it, though..  I think this could work. I just didn't see it in the docs initially. Seems I could just do a status check on the token each time before a user makes an entry in my app  (if they have the fb share option enabled), then have them refresh it if necessary before the entry is submitted.